# How convert int's to byte array with two fixed values

Tags: c#, arrays, arduino

I'm sending five bytes to an Arduino:

```
byte[] { 0xF1, byte1, byte2, byte3, 0x33 }
```

The values of `byte1`, `byte2` and `byte3` are dynamic. The first and last bytes are always the same.

Byte values are from 0 to 255.

How can I simply convert `int`s to bytes and put them into my byte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your values won't exceed the byte range `[0, 255]`, you can simply cast them:

```
byte[] b = { 0xF1, (byte)byte1, (byte)byte2, (byte)byte3, 0x33 }
```

In alternative you can use [`Convert.ToByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5949zd89.aspx), which throws an `OverflowException` if values are less than 0 or greater than 255.

Answer (score 1):

To get array of bytes from int use:

```
    byte[] intAsArrayOfBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(yourInt);
```

then you can copy values to your array

```
   byte[] { 0xF1, intAsArrayOfBytes[0], intAsArrayOfBytes[1], intAsArrayOfBytes[3], 0x33 }
```

or if you need just convert int type into byte type and you know that variable between 0..255 use:

```
   byte byte1 = (byte) int1;
   byte byte2 = (byte) int2;
   byte byte3 = (byte) int3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ints are between 0 and 255, use [Convert.ToByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobyte.aspx). For example:

```
int byte1;
int byte2;
int byte3;
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 0xF1, Convert.ToByte(byte1), 
    Convert.ToByte(byte2), Convert.ToByte(byte3), 0x33 };
```